# How do Lasso coefficients change as lambda approaches infinity

Tags: regression-coefficients, lasso, regularization

[image]

I have encountered such a problem. I think 2, 3 and 4 pictures are true, but no.
Can anyone help?

Comment: Please add the `[self-study]` tag & read its 
[wiki](https://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/self-study/info). Then tell us 
what you understand thus far, what you've tried & where you're stuck. We'll 
provide hints to help you get unstuck. Please make these changes as just 
posting your homework & hoping someone will do it for you is grounds for closing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the Lagrangian form of Lasso

$$\hat{\beta}^{lasso} = argmin_\beta \{ \frac{1}{2}\sum_{i=1}^{N}(y_i - \beta_0 - \sum_{j=1}^{p} x_{ij} \beta_j)^2  + \lambda\sum_{j=1}^{p} |\beta_j|\}$$

as shown in [The Elements of Statistical Learning](https://web.stanford.edu/~hastie/Papers/ESLII.pdf), page 68, Eq. 3.52.
As $\lambda$ approaches $\infty$, what would the coefficients in $\beta$ need to look like to minimize this ?